# Galera Geo-replication: [WSREP] P: no nodes coming from prim view, prim not possible

Tags: mysql, galera

First time trying the "segmentation" on mysql+galera setup, however it didnt go well so far.

setup is 9 servers, distributed over 3 datacenter, and each datacenter holds 3 servers.

note: Firewall is disabled (testing environment)

When I do #mysqld_bootstrap

it seems to work

```
mysql> show status like 'wsrep_cluster_size';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| wsrep_cluster_size | 9     |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But few seconds later all mysql nodes go down with the following error:

```
2022-01-23T15:54:44.873480Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'wsrep_slave_threads' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use wsrep_applier_threads instead.
2022-01-23T15:54:44.875534Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26-26.8) starting as process 1359
2022-01-23T15:54:44.888883Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000000] [WSREP] P: Option 'gcs.fc_master_slave' is deprecated and will be removed in the future versions, please use 'gcs.fc_single_primary' instead. 
2022-01-23T15:54:44.921771Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000000] [WSREP] P: access file(/var/lib/mysql//gvwstate.dat) failed(No such file or directory)
2022-01-23T15:54:51.917372Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000000] [WSREP] P: no nodes coming from prim view, prim not possible
2022-01-23T15:55:15.456806Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [WSREP] P: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 110: failed to reach primary view: 110 (Connection timed out)
     at /home/galera/galera-4-26.4.10/gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():160
2022-01-23T15:55:15.458479Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [WSREP] P: /home/galera/galera-4-26.4.10/gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():219: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
2022-01-23T15:55:15.458702Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [WSREP] P: /home/galera/galera-4-26.4.10/gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1632: Failed to open channel 'galera4' at 'gcomm://157.245.33.247,157.245.33.248,157.245.41.33,161.35.25.120,161.35.25.171,161.35.25.245,51.15.252.215,51.158.118.146,212.47.227.5': -110 (Connection timed out)
2022-01-23T15:55:15.458774Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [WSREP] P: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
2022-01-23T15:55:15.458823Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [WSREP] wsrep::connect(gcomm://157.245.33.247,157.245.33.248,157.245.41.33,161.35.25.120,161.35.25.171,161.35.25.245,51.15.252.215,51.158.118.146,212.47.227.5) failed: 7
2022-01-23T15:55:15.458906Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-01-23T15:55:15.500245Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.26-26.8)  MySQL Wsrep Server - GPL
```

My mysql config file looks like this

```
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size=128M
binlog_format=ROW
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_node_name="Galera-SCW-03"
wsrep_node_address="212.47.227.5"
wsrep_cluster_name="galera4"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://157.245.33.247,157.245.33.248,157.245.41.33,161.35.25.120,161.35.25.171,161.35.25.245,51.15.252.215,51.158.118.146,212.47.227.5"
wsrep_provider_options="gmcast.segment=3; gcache.size=128M; gcache.page_size=128M"
wsrep_slave_threads=4
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
```

am I missing something here? I could find a clear documentation for geo-replication using galera+mysql.

Any help would be appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

Notice this sentence in PXC Doc:
[Each node of the cluster must use the same SSL certificates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7u7V.png)

So what we need to do is to transfer these certi-files from 1st node to every other nodes:

```
# 1st node
[root@m1 data]# cd $PXC_DATADIR
[root@m1 data]# scp *.pem m2:/data/mysql/mysql3306/data/
```

then start 1st node with --wsrep-new-cluster or bootstrap mode, and the others in normal mode:

```
# 1st node
[root@m1 data]# mysqld --defaults-file=/data/mysql/mysql3306/my3306.cnf --wsrep-new-cluster &

# other nodes
# change permission first
[root@m2 data]# chown mysql.mysql *.pem
# then start in normal mode
[root@m2 data]# mysqld --defaults-file=/data/mysql/mysql3306/my3306.cnf &
```